# Multinational and multilingual content

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, internationalization, hreflang, cctld

I would like to get some guidance on international SEO.

For now this is how my website looks like:

```
website.com
website.com/fr
website.com/it
```

I would like to make it region plus language specific, this is my approach

```
website.com/en-us
website.com/fr-fr
website.com/it-it
```

I would like to understand what my next steps should be ?
Should I redirect:

```
website.com to website.com/en-us 
website.com/fr to website.com/fr-fr
website.com/it to website.com/it-it
```

I saw that some websites kept the.com for english speakers in the us (instead of .com/en-us) so I am not sure what to do here. Should I keep a consistent structure or can I have a mix of website.com and website.com/fr-fr?

Also the way my website is set up is that it automatically combine any language with any location, so it means that I can have:

```
website.com/it-us 
website.com/en-fr
website.com/fr-it
```

But I don't want Google to index all the combinations because sometimes it doesn't make sense (eg Italian in Australia) and I don't want to have a crazy list of hreflang tags with all my combinations (it would be around 200)in my header.
Is it possible to not have hreflang tags for those pages and add instead the following tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to avoid indexation?

Thanks!